# Download file to browser (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have to download file from server to browser. The code actually works, but it appends '_' characters to the beginning and end of the file.
Could you please help me to solve that? I have no idea why that strange stuff happens...

Here's the codes:

`Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\" + "p.jpg" + "\")
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_data/PROJECTS_DATA/p.jpg"))`

Answer (score 0):

Use Below:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
```

Comment: yes, it works with image, but the thing is that I my application I want to transfer not only image files, but .zip, .rar and etc